# Is break; required after die() php

Tags: php, logic, switch-statement, case, control-structure

I've been thinking to much...

In the area of switch case is `break;` required after `die()`

Example:

```
switch($i){

     case 0:
          die('Case without break;');

     case 1:
          die('Case with break;');
          break;

}
```

Comment: It's not necessary, because the script could NEVER actually reach the break line, because you just killed the script with the `die()` call. It's kind of like ordering food for a dead person. Maybe it has some meaning for you, but that person's not going to be around to eat it.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I figured.  I just thought I'd ask around and see what other people had to say about it.  Nice analogy by the way.

Answer (score 6):

[`die()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) is just an alias for [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php), where exit() will terminate the program flow  immediately. (Shutdown functions and object destructors will still get executed after `exit()`)

And no, it is not a syntax error to omit the `break`, on the contrary there are many useful cases for omitting the `break`. Check the manual page of the [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement for examples.

Comment: Thanks for that additional info!  I was not aware of the relationship.

Comment: Yeah, found this interesting once too. :) I don't know why they have so much aliases in PHP. Also you should know that if you pass a string to `die()` - what is seen in most application scenarios - it has a direct influence on the return value. If you craft a framework a I would use a function like `panic($string)` which will print the message using `echo` and afterwards calls `exit(1);`

Comment: Was not aware of that either.

Comment: Check this it is funny (if you not have to debug this) : `die('001 Script Error');` will have a return value of `0 - Success` as the string will be converted to a number: `0`. Had this once, debugging this made me going crazy!!! %)

Answer (score 4):

it's not required. Even for the switch `break` is not mandatory. If no break is in one case, it just keeps executing the next.

but after `die`, it makes no difference, since die terminates the program execution. Just hope you don't plan to use `die` inside some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, it is **not** required, but it won't be executed since `die()` causes the execution to stop.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Thanks for a straight up answer!

Comment: I do not believe this is required syntactically.

Comment: Syntactically `break` is not required after `case` in PHP.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ  Thank you look of disapproval :)